# SvelteKit - Asset Handling: Transformed .webp image not found on nested route in Production/Preview

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I am loading the transformed .webp image on `/about-us/social-responsibilities` page. I referred https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/assets#caching-and-inlining for loading assets.

Everything works fine when I run the `npm run dev`, but transformed images return 404 when I run `npm run preview` or when I deploy it on vercel.

```
<script>    
import supportImg from '$lib/assets/images/we-support-farmers-soldiers.jpg?webp';
</script>

<div>
<img src={supportImg} loading="lazy">
</div>
```

The image returns 404 because it tries to load it from `/about-us/_app/immutable/assets/we-support-farmers-soldiers-17dde5c7.webp`. It will work fine if it loads the image from `/_app/immutable/assets/we-support-farmers-soldiers-17dde5c7.webp`. But I am not able to find the way to do it.

Comment: Did you solve it ? If you did, can you please how to do? best